# Request with 2 many to many with sequelize (merge result)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I would like to know how can I "merge" the result to get result from 2 tables.

Currently I have 3 tables :

- posts [id, title...]
- feeds [id, fk_people_id, fk_post_id]
- posts_peoples [id, fk_people_id, fk_post_id]

I would like to return the posts where people is present in **feeds** table and **posts_peoples** table.

When I run this request, I have only the post where people is present in **feeds** table :

```
// Request
const resultRequest = await db.Post.findAll({
    include: [
    {
        model: db.Feed,
        as: "Feed",
        where: {
            fk_people_id: 2,
        },
    },
    ],
})
```

When I run this request, I have only the post where people is present in **posts_peoples** table :

```
// Request
const resultRequest = await db.Post.findAll({
    include: [
    {
        model: db.PostPeople,
        as: "PostPeople",
        where: {
            fk_people_id: 2,
        },
    },
    ],
})
```

When I add **feeds** and **posts_peoples**, it doesn't work.

```
// Request
const resultRequest = await db.Post.findAll({
    include: [
    {
        model: db.Feed,
        as: "Feed",
        where: {
            fk_people_id: 2,
        },
    },
    {
        model: db.PostPeople,
        as: "PostPeople",
        where: {
            fk_people_id: 2,
        },
    },
    ],
})
```

The result is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Add `required: false` to your includes to generate SQL with a LEFT JOIN to include results from both tables.

```js
// Request
const resultRequest = await db.Post.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: db.Feed,
        as: "Feed",
        where: {
            fk_people_id: 2,
        },
        required: false,
    },
    {
        model: db.PostPeople,
        as: "PostPeople",
        where: {
            fk_people_id: 2,
        },
        required: false,
    }],
})
```